# Do you have to leave right away when resigning during probation period?

Tags: job-change, resignation, probation

As I know, during the probation, both employer and employee can cancel contract with (without) a short notice.

- Employer: A friend of mine said, he had 6 months probation, but at the 4th month, his manager called him in and said that they had to let him go because of abc, and they asked him to leave the office immediately, but they still paid him until his 6 months probation finished.
- How about employee? If a contract says, employee has 1 month notice to resign from probation period, will he have to leave office immediately after handing the resignation letter? Or does he has to stay until next month?

I mean, it doesn't make sense if employee has to stay, because he is still in probation, and it doesn't help for both him and company if he stays.

Comment: Being asked to leave the office immediately but still being paid for 1-2 months is essentially giving you 1-2 months notice. Whether you should stay in the office and keep working during that period is up to the employer, no matter who gives notice.

Comment: What country is this?  A country tag would be helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Or does he has to stay until next month?

Ultimately that is up to the manager or boss to decide. When you present your resignation within your notice period, two things can happen:

1. They decide to terminate you right away. That means that you should pack and leave the premises that same day/moment.
2. They take your resignation and still have you stay the rest of the Notice Period, so you (and they) can carry out any termination process required (password changes, finishing some critical project, etc.).

Even though you were in probation, *if* a notice period was specified and agreed on, you should try to stick to it if possible; not doing something you agreed may be unprofessional from your part.

You say it doesn't make sense as it is of no help for anybody, but that may not necessarily be true; it depends on each specific situation and on your manager's call if there are still things to be done in that period, so I would not take if for granted that you can walk away right away, even though you were on probation (so no strong or formal contracts have been signed still).

Comment: Yes, exactly. If the contract states 1 month notice period, then you are obligated to stay the duration of your notice. Management may choose to relieve you of that obligation, but that is at their discretion.